# how to upload joomla 1.5 file to hoster site if i don`t have installer file ,only html ,css ,php and xml file

Tags: templates, joomla1.5, joomla-template

i`m new to make joomla template each time i upload my template i get this message:
Installer: :Install: File does not exist /home2/computin/public_html/computingmadeasy/joomlatest/tmp/install_4f3440a5e1186/Camping.se/views

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to install a template right? Actually you dont need an install file, your xml file contains all the information to joomla installer. Check your xml file that is there any files listed in xml and not in your template package.